# Accessing hidden data streams

Tags: alternate-data-stream

Once you've found a hidden data stream, how do you access it? I'm using windows and I have found the file in C:documents\file7.txt:hiddensecret.txt.

Complete newbie in training thanks.

Comment: Its part of a course for beginners.  1st question was to find which folder the hidden stream is in and the 2nd part is to access the information within the txt file. I've tried notepad file7.txt:hiddensecret.txt this command opens notepad but just asks if i want to make a new file?

Comment: The drive should contain C:\ and the filename cannot have a : (colon) in it, and specifying a filename as the parameter to notepad will not open the file.

Answer (score 0):

List of Notepad command line parameters:

There is but a limited set of command line options:

```
/A <filename> open file as ansi
/W <filename> open file as unicode
/P <filename> print filename
/PT <filename> <printername> <driverdll> <port> print filename to designated printer
```

There is no switch to disable file menu functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Go to cmd and go to the directory then `C:\Users\your_username\documents>expand file7.txt:hiddensecret.txt filname.txt(the filename and ext(i.e txt,jpg,mp4 etc) you want it in)`
Here "expand" is a built in microsoft utility that will extract/copy the file into the folder where it will be visible and accessible.